# Unbable to isolate Ajax rendered area for ui:include loaded view in richfaces 4.x

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I want to develop a web app that contains an "Menu Area" and "Active Area". That "Active Area" points to a page in the "Controller" managed bean and loads it by ajax request. The page to be loaded is set by ajax request through "A4j:Commandlink" and renders the "Active Area'. Here is the code.

### 1. Index.xhtml

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
      <ui:define name="menu">
           <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
      </ui:define>

      <ui:define name="body">
           <h:panel width="100%" id="mainPanel">
                     <ui:include id="MainIncludeArea" src="#{controller.currentView}"/>
           </h:panel>
      </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
```

### 2. Menu.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
      <h:form id="menuForm">
           <ul>
                <li><a4j:commandLink value="Include 1" render="mainPanel" actionListener="#{controller.setInclude1}" /> </li>
           </ul>
      </h:form>
 </ui:composition>
```

### 3. Include1.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
      Included Page 1
      <h:form id="f1">
           <a4j:commandButton id="cb1" actionListener="#{controller.action}" value="click"/>
      </h:form>
 </ui:composition>
```

### 4. Controller.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Controller {
    String currentView;
   public Controller() {
      this.currentView = "include.xhtml";
    }

   public void action() {
      System.out.println("### Button Clicked ###");
    }

     public void setInclude1() {
      currentView = "include_1.xhtml";
    }

    public String getCurrentView() {
      System.out.println(" ### returning view ###" + currentView);
      return currentView;
    }
}
```

Now, when a page is loaded to active area that as you see contains a "a4j:commandButton" with an actionListener, if the button is clicked, instead of calling the listener method, the page is loaded again, and the when the second time the button is clicked,  the page is loaded as well as the listener method is called. Which means that whole page is refreshed again and view is then set and method is called. In richfaces 3.3.x, I used to use "a4j:include"  for the active area. Everything worked fine. Now in richfaces 4.x, I have to use ui:include component.  3.3.x had “a4j:region” component to isolate a region. But in 4.x its bahavious has been changed.

Now I dont know how to isolate this region to be re-rendered and the Ajax request. I want only the active area to be changed instead of the whole page to be refreshed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using composite components in my JSF 2.0 application, and I often face the same problem. So I use [this helper class](http://blog.timmlinder.com/2011/07/jsf2-finding-and-re-rendering-components-in-different-namingcontainers/):

```
public class ComponentResolver {
    /**
     * Returns the absolute path of a given {@link UIComponent}.
     * E.g. :namingContainer1:namingContainer2:componentId.
     *
     * @param currentComponent
     * @return The absolute path of the given component
     */
    public String getAbsoluteComponentPath(UIComponent currentComponent) {
        final char separatorChar = UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());

        String path = "";
        if(!(currentComponent instanceof NamingContainer))
            path = currentComponent.getId();
        while(currentComponent != null) {
            if(currentComponent instanceof NamingContainer) {
                path = currentComponent.getId() + (!path.isEmpty() ? separatorChar : "") + path;
            }
            currentComponent = currentComponent.getParent();
        }
        path = separatorChar + path;
        return path;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a whitespace-separated list of the absolute paths of all given components.
     *
     * @param components The list of components
     * @return A whitespace-separated list of all absolute paths.
     * @see ComponentResolver#getAbsoluteComponentPath(UIComponent)
     */
    public String getAbsoluteComponentPaths(Collection<UIComponent> components) {
        String paths = "";
        for(UIComponent c : components) {
            if(!paths.isEmpty())
                paths += " ";
            paths += getAbsoluteComponentPath(c);
        }
        return paths;
    }

    /**
     * Finds all components with the given id, and returns a whitespace-separated list
     * of their absolute paths (e.g. <code>:j_id1:j_id2:myId :j_id1:j_id3:myId</code>).
     *
     * @param id The id to search the component tree for
     * @return Whitespace-separated list of absolute component paths
     * @see #resolveList(String)
     */
    public String resolve(String id) {
        List<UIComponent> components = resolveList(id);
        return getAbsoluteComponentPaths(components);
    }

    public String resolveWithoutRootPrefix(String id) {
        List<UIComponent> components = resolveList(id);
        String result = getAbsoluteComponentPaths(components);
        return result.substring(1, result.length());
    }

    /**
     * Finds all components with the given id by traversing the component tree.
     * @param id Id to search for.
     * @return List of components that have got this id.
     */
    public List<UIComponent> resolveList(String id)
    {
        return resolveList(id, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot());
    }

    /**
     * Recursive function that traverses the component tree and accumulates all components
     * that match the given id.
     * @param id The id to look for
     * @param currentComponent Component of the tree to start traversal at
     * @return Accumulation of all components that match the given id
     */
    private List<UIComponent> resolveList(String id, UIComponent currentComponent) {
        List<UIComponent> accumulator = new LinkedList<UIComponent>();

        if(null != currentComponent.getId() && currentComponent.getId().equals(id)) {
            accumulator.add(currentComponent);
        }

        Iterator<UIComponent> childIt = currentComponent.getFacetsAndChildren();
        while(childIt.hasNext()) {
            UIComponent child = childIt.next();
            accumulator.addAll(resolveList(id, child));
        }

        return accumulator;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to set it as a manage bean, and use it as follow:

```
#{componentResolver.resolve('myRegion')}
```

So now you just need to set the id of the aimed region as `myRegion` and set the `render` attribute of your commandLink with the previous EL.

That's pretty tricky, but I didn't find any other solution for working with nested blocs in JSF 2.0.

[(source)](http://blog.timmlinder.com/2011/07/jsf2-finding-and-re-rendering-components-in-different-namingcontainers/)